# A strange path is being printed for an entry when netstat command is used?

Tags: command-line, networking, netstat

When I used the netstat -a command to check for active connections, I encountered this entry under active unix domains sockets(servers and established)

```
Proto  Refcnt  Flags        Type      State        I-node              Path
unix    2      [ ]         DGRAM                    32773    @@@@2@@��@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

I am new to networking. What is implied by this?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It seems to be related to GPU. Let's wait that someone explains it. Upvoted.

Comment: Here is the output of `netstat -a | grep -e Path -e '@@@@'` command in my Ubuntu 20.04 notebook: ```Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  5      [ ]         DGRAM                    47263    @var/run/nvidia-xdriver-24776835@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    29074    @var/run/nvidia-xdriver-cd91bb22@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Comment: Can you pipe the output *of the relevant* line to `| hd` so we can see the details of these strange characters?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I typed the command you provided and all I get is `Binary File(Standard Input) matches`.

Comment: Something like this: `netstat -a | grep -e '@@@@' | hd` ?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Here is the ouput: `00000000  42 69 6e 61 72 79 20 66  69 6c 65 20 28 73 74 61  |Binary file (sta|
00000010  6e 64 61 72 64 20 69 6e  70 75 74 29 20 6d 61 74  |ndard input) mat|
00000020  63 68 65 73 0a                                    |ches.|
00000025`

Comment: Something is badly wrong with `netstat` or the network stack in your system. Does this persist reboots? I upvoted your question too...

Comment: I just rebooted. It still exists. With a different I-node value and a 6 instead of 2 in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I also had that path in my netstat output.

As it turns out it apparently belongs to uml_switch,
which appears to be a program to assist with network access from user-mode Linux.

The program is being called with the following cmdline:

```
/usr/bin/uml_switch -unix /var/run/uml-utilities/uml_switch.ctl
```

I'm not sure if that's actually something to be concerned about.
Howewver I did build user-mode Linux and I can imagine that simply to be a bug that not many people encountered.

I simply used:

```
sudo lsof | grep INODE
```

with INODE being the value associated to that string that has been encountered with netstat.

That being said if you installed it via apt,
you can probably remove it with

```
sudo apt remove uml-utilities
```